# How can I ignore the host name when testing that an HTML attribute contains an expected URL?

Tags: ruby, regex, rspec, capybara

I am writting a test to check if meta tag exists and if the content matches. Look at the example below:

```
def have_meta(name, expected)
    page.find "meta[property='#{name}'][content='#{expected}']", :visible => false
end
```

I am calling the function as below:

```
have_meta("og:title", "this is the title")
have_meta("og:url", "http://www.lorem.com/ipsum")
```

The problem is that my url contents changes based on which environment I am working in. E.g. It can be:

```
http://www.lorem.com/ipsum
```

or

```
http://www.sdfsd.com/ipsum
```

I want to have a regex match for the "content" part of Meta. Ignoring the main url but checking the "ipsum" part. Do you know how can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use CSS's ends-with attribute selector:

```
def have_meta_with_path(name, path)
  page.find "meta[property='#{name}'][content$='#{path}']", :visible => false
end
```

where `path` is just e.g. '/ipsum'. No regex needed. It will be safest to have two methods: your original `have_meta`, which tests the entire value, and the one above, which tests the end. You wouldn't want to just test the end of the `og:title`.

Comment: Thanks Dave for the help. Thats what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You could use XPath instead of CSS.

```
page.should have_xpath "//meta[@property='og:url'][contains(@content, 'ipsum')]"
```